# Google file/folder in multiple location editing from different folders

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I was wondering if I had a `doc A` that was **saved in two separate folder locations**, if there was a way for me to **edit the document in one folder and the edits would also show in the other saved `doc A` in the other folder**?
Almost like the way labels work in gmail.

Comment: Are you editing a Docs editor in the cloud, or a document that is edited with a program on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

#### YES.

You can do that for **any file or folder** by creating a shortcut using **<kbd>`ALT`</kbd>** **while dragging the file/folder** to another location in your drive.

You will notice the small `+` sign under the file/folder

[image: create a shortcut in Google Drive]

In the new location you can notice the little arrow stating that this is a shortcut.

[image]

Also. When right clicking the file, you will find the new option `Show file location`

[image]

Comment: Welcome.
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.